# take part of number in cell and move the remaining to another cell + excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I need to divide one number into sum of two numbers .. in my example (Calculating end of service benefits) I need to divide 13 years to 5 years in cell and 8 years in cell for example .. if the total years = 4 years it should be divided into 4 and 0 and so on ..

```
      A           B               C                 D                E
 start date | End date  | number of years  | first 5 years  | Remaining years
 5/5/2010     6/3/2016          5                 5                  0
 4/3/2000     7/7/2013          13                5                  8
 3/6/1998     13/5/2016         17                5                  12
 1/1/2013     2/3/2016          3                 3                  0
```

How could we calculate D & E columns .. any help will be appreciated .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set formula in D as (for instance, D2):

```
=IF(C2 > 5 , 5 , C2)
```

and in column E:

```
=IF(C2 > 5 , C2 - 5 , 0)
```

Then, **drag** the formula down to cover your whole range (e.g. from D2/E2 to D5/E5).

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for, you may consider making it as "the" answer.